# Recruiters on Stack Overflow Careers

Tags: discussion, support, jobs

I wanted to send an email, but Careers seems to keep sending me here.

I was just contacted by a recruiter on Stack Overflow Careers about a job that was with another company.

*I have already talked to that company in person anyway* which clearly he didn't know.

This actually made me feel slightly sick, I don't want recruiters infesting SOC and it turning out like LinkedIn. I was hoping there would be a report button on the inbox message but there wasn't.

It wasn't just that it was a 3rd party recruiter for a company it was the fact they said "if this doesn't interest you I have many other roles ... blah" ughh vom!

This isn't a question so I don't see why "feedback welcome" links to meta.stack.

Comment: Not everything on meta needs to be a *question* in the traditional sense. A lot of posts around here are feature requests, bug reports, discussions, etc. You did the right thing by coming here. You can reach the Careers team by email through `careers@stackoverflow.com`, and they also monitor the [meta-tag:careers] tag, but I'm going to pass your post along regardless.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm sorry that his message rubbed you the wrong way, but as far as messages go it was pretty good.

We do in fact allow recruiters on Careers, as long as they adhere to some key rules: They need to disclose the company they are recruiting for, and have to be recruiting for a specific role (rather than saying: I have a bunch of openings at a bunch of companies, wanna talk?). And it would be nice if the role was relevant to your interests, and if there was some background info. In this case all four points were hit.

It *is* annoying to be contacted about the some role twice, but unfortunately, there is no good way in Careers at the moment for the company to let the recruiter know who they spoke to already.

When it comes to recruiters, it's not as straightforward as "All recruiters are bad". Some are, some are not. We feel that there is a space for the good ones on Careers, but will proactively reach out to recruiters if we see they are less than stellar or if one of our users points one out to us (up to and including cancelling their subscription and refunding them). Per @anna-lear if you want to report spammy messages please email careers@stackoverflow.com.

Comment: I have just been contacted by a recruiter for an irrelevant role and they have not disclosed the company they are recruiting for. It seems however that there is no way to report them?