# Does SO/SE share Careers data with other websites?

Tags: discussion, jobs

I got a Careers message (via Careers messaging) from a recruiter, containing "I came across your resume on DICE" . DICE seems to be another jobs platform. Does Stack Overflow share my Careers data with them?

Also, that recruiter just mentioned the city of the Job, not the company looking for a developer, don't they have to declare it (https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188594/298181)?

And they asked about my updated résumé, isn't that why I have an up-to-date Careers profile?

Comment: Just to clarify; you received this message via Careers messaging or a direct email?

Comment: Via Careers messaging

Answer (score 9):

Thanks for bringing this to our attention. Per Patrick's answer and Dean's comment we don't share information.

As for your other point, you are correct that they need to identify the company they're recruiting for. We'll reach out to the recruiter and work with them on both that and on double checking messages when copy/pasting.

Answer (score 8):

No. From the [privacy policy page](https://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy):

> If you post a profile on Careers, employers can see your name, and if you apply for a job, we give them your contact info.

SOI does not give your information to other without asking or your consent to do so.

Your location isn't shared, but it is possible you have done it yourself, through your LinkedIn account, some other fields you have filled in, or your current company name.

Comment: Yup, this is spot on. We don't share your profile with any third parties.